# Can i add JPanels to a JFrame with Graphics already on it?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

So I recently started playing around with java graphics and have encountered an issue. I have drawn images onto a JFrame, but did not learn that the images' bounds cannot overlap each other if they're all in one JFrame (setting bounds over where another image is makes the image disappear). I heard something about using multiple JPanels to fix this. I do not know how to do this since I used a JFrame and not a JPanel in my program, so some help would be appreciated on this issue. Thank you, and I apologize if this question is dumb. (My other question that others seem to think was the same as this one was an issue of setting bounds, this question regards bounds overlapping and covering each other)
Here are my classes:

Window Class-

```
package game.thirdTry;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static Window instance;
    public static Window getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Window("Game");
        }
        return instance;
    }
    private Window(String name) {
        super(name);
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
        //setUndecorated(true);
        addKeyListener(new UserInput());
        //this.getContentPane().getSize();

        WindowStructure banner = new WindowStructure("Beatles Logo.jpg", 0, 0, getWidth(), 75);
        //WindowStructure fball = new WindowStructure("fireball.100x100.png", 100, 100, 100, 100);

        WindowStructure fball = WindowStructure.getInstanceF();

        System.out.println("Fball.xSize: " + fball.xSize + ", Fball.ySize: " + fball.ySize);
        System.out.println("Fball.xLoc: " + fball.xLoc + ", Fball.yLoc: " + fball.yLoc);
        //banner.setBounds(banner.xLoc, banner.yLoc, banner.xSize, banner.ySize);
        //fball.setBounds(fball.xLoc, fball.yLoc, fball.xLoc + fball.xSize, fball.ySize + fball.ySize);
        banner.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        fball.setBounds(0, 75, getWidth(), getHeight());
        add(fball, null);
        add(banner, null);

        setVisible(true);

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Fball.xLoc: " + fball.xLoc + ", Fball.yLoc: " + fball.yLoc);
            repaint();
            try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
/*
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
    }
*/
}
```

Image Class-

```
package game.thirdTry;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class WindowStructure extends JPanel {

    private static WindowStructure fball;

    public static WindowStructure getInstanceF(){
        if(fball == null){
            fball = new WindowStructure("fireball.100x100.png", 0, 75, 100, 100);
        }
        return fball;
    }
    ImageIcon imageIcon;
    int xLoc, yLoc, xSize, ySize;

    public WindowStructure(String bannerImg, int xLoc, int yLoc, int xSize, int ySize){
        URL bannerImgURL = getClass().getResource(bannerImg);
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(bannerImgURL);
        this.xLoc = xLoc;
        this.yLoc = yLoc;
        this.xSize = xSize;
        this.ySize = ySize;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), xLoc, yLoc, xSize, ySize, null);
    }
}
```

KeyListener / User Input Class-

```
package game.thirdTry;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class UserInput implements KeyListener {
    // Window window = Window.getInstance();
    WindowStructure fball = WindowStructure.getInstanceF();

    boolean goUp = false;
    boolean goDown = false;
    boolean goLeft = false;
    boolean goRight = false;

    public void moveUpDown() {
        if (goUp && goDown) {
            if (fball.yLoc > 0) {
                fball.yLoc -= 10;
            }
        } else if (goUp) {
            if (fball.yLoc > -5) {
                fball.yLoc -= 10;
            }
        } else if (goDown) {
            if (fball.yLoc < 480) {
                fball.yLoc += 10;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("moveUpDown() method called");
    }

    public void moveLeftRight() {
        if (goLeft && goRight) {
            if (fball.xLoc < 1100) {
                fball.xLoc += 10;
            }
        } else if (goRight) {
            if (fball.xLoc < 1110) {
                fball.xLoc += 10;
            }
        } else if (goLeft) {
            if (fball.xLoc > 0) {
                fball.xLoc -= 10;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            goUp = true;
            goDown = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            goDown = true;
            goUp = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            goLeft = true;
            goRight = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            goRight = true;
            goLeft = false;
        }
        moveUpDown();
        moveLeftRight();
        System.out.println("keyPressed() was called");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            goUp = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            goDown = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            goLeft = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            goRight = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: `did not learn that the images' bounds cannot overlap each other if they're all in one JFrame (setting bounds over where another image is makes the image disappear).` - not true, I explained how you can do this in your last question asked 5 days ago. `since I used a JFrame and not a JPanel in my program` Your WindowStructure class extends JPanel so you are using a JPanel. Why are you even using a custom class? You can just use a JLabel to display an image.

Comment: By extending JPanel I dont actually declare a JPanel. How am i supposed to use multiple JPanels then, or do I not even need to do this since I'm going to use the setOpaque() method (I went back and looked at the old question, I'm still not fully clear on what I need to do) I really do not like using JLabels sinc my I understand my custom class more and would prefer to do it that way. Thanks for all the help so far

Comment: `By extending JPanel I dont actually declare a JPanel.` - Every WindowStructure object `is a` JPanel. You have all the property of a panel and you use the WindowStructure exactly the same way you would use a JPanel. `I really do not like using JLabels` - all you do with the JLabel is set the location of the label.

Comment: `My other question that others seem to think was the same as this one was an issue of setting bounds, this question regards bounds overlapping and covering each other` - and in the other question you asked a follow up question in the comment and you were given an answser that each panel needs to be `non-opaque`. Another reason for using a JLabel because a JLabel is opaque and all you need to worry about is setting the location of the label.

Comment: I'll look more into JLabels later, but back to the setOpaque(true) method: I implemented it in the constructor of the WindowStructure class and it didn't change anything. The bounds of my two images still cannot overlap else one of the images is covered up. Some example code would be great if you could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), xLoc, yLoc, xSize, ySize, null);
```

The problem is that you are scaling the image as you paint the image. Therefore the image takes up the entire window space and so yes it paints over top of the image painted first.

Just paint the image at its real size:

```
g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), xLoc, yLoc,  this);
```

This is another reason to use a JLabel. You don't need to worry about the size. You just position the label at a specific location and the image will be painted. The code is much simpler. And using this approach you don't need to worry about making the panel non-opaque.

The problem with your code now is that you need to make the panel a large size because you are painting the image relative to your WindowStructure panel. So if your image is (25 x 25) and you want the image painted at (100, 100), you need to make the panel (125, 125), which means the panel need to be transparent so the part of the panel that does not contain the image is not painted. Using a JLable, the size of the label will always be (25, 25) so you simple set the location of the label and only (25, 25) pixels will be painted.

> I'll look more into JLabels later

Look at it now. There is no time like the present!

Also, your WindowStructure class has a terrible design. There is no need for the static methods and variables. Each image should be independent of one another.